# What to do when handling two asynchronous queries when the second query takes that result of the first one

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous

This is for Android, SQLite query. I will write details below but since this question can be generalized, I will ask in such manner first.

I have two methods, method A and method B. They are both asynchronized query methods.

When method A is **complete** and got the result **in the background**, I want to fire method B, taking the **result from A as parameter**.

How should I achieve this?

-Details-
Both method A and method B use AsyncQueryHandler (different instances.)

Method A queries Table 1, gets an item back, and I get it.

I wanna throw in the item from Table 1 in method B as parameter, and then let it query Table 2.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: When they depend on each other why separate them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you want is the behaviour of a promise, let method A do something in the background, then upon completion it promises to return the result.Then Method B, accepts the promise only then, and performs it tasks. To achieve this in android, it would best to use rxandroid which is based on observables.The idea is to listen and then react to observations made by consumers.

Comment: I would also consider using a dependency injection framework to inject your dependency, thus achieving loose coupling between methods. Dagger2 is fast and works well.

Comment: Thank you, I saw some needs for observables with some research but I couldn't quite get the specific tool. I'll definitely look into RxAndroid. I appreciate your answer!